# Standard backup/restore using the internal iPhone Web Server

Tags: iphone, backup, webserver, internal

Does anybody know, if there is an open source solution available
to backup/restore files/directories from iPhone to Mac/PCs?
I thought using the internal iPhone Web Server and a connect
via browser might be the standard procedure ?
Any help would be appreciated ..
Thanks Matthias

PS: I just wanna implement a backup feature in one of my iPhone Apps and
I'm looking for a ready to run open source library / source code samples
which demonstrate the file transfer (a sqlite + a few image files, 
stored in the document path of my iPhone app) 
to the file system of a client (MAC/PC).
May be with on the fly data compression ?
1. starting the internal Web Server in my iPhone app 
2. client connect (browser) to the iPhone web server
3. download files to the client.

Comment: I take it you want something independent of iTunes' backup?

Comment: None of what you're describing could possibly called "standard procedure". Standard procedure is to hook up to iTunes and sync. In a few weeks when iOS 5 comes out, that can happen over WiFi instead.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't completely understand the question, but here you go (open source solution??):

Backing up and restoring iOS devices: iCloud, Wireless Syncing in iOS 5, get a beta copy by becoming a paid registered developer or wait until the fall

Backing up and restoring Macs: Time Machine, buy a Time Capsule, connect a hard drive directly to the Macs and Apple makes it REALLY easy to back up and restore, I love my Time Capsule, OR buy a Mac Server instead of a Time Capsule and back up all of your Macs to that

Backing up and restoring PCs: Well, since it's going to crash anyway, you better look into this but I'm not sure about PCs

Answer (score 0):

iOS 5 has got [**iCloud**](http://www.apple.com/icloud/) which does the backup job. As an additional feature, it also makes sure the data in your iPhone is synced with the data in your iPad etc.

The downside being this is only for iOS 5 supported devices. I doubt there is anything out there which provides this seamless integration across devices.

If you want to do something on your own, the use `sqlite` or `filestore` in iOS devices,  use [**ASIHTTP**](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) as your library, hit your server where you want to store & sync data from client to server.

Answer (score 0):

For a seamless integration across all iOS versions, 
we will integrate a WebServer into our app, 
which allows the user to backup all user data (saved in the documents directory on iPhone)
on a PC/MAC (browser based) and restore it later.